# Issues while implementing a PHP session token

Tags: php, html, session, token, csrf-protection

I'm trying to implement CSRF protection to a webform. Its a one page website that captures data, posts it to a PHP file which then emails me the information. The webpage functions as intended (minus the security).

I'm having the following issues:

1. I can't work out how to implement the PHP code to set the token; converting index.html to index.php loads a blank body. I think that resolving this would likely fix my issues.
2. When I try and call token.php from jQuery, I get a 403 error.
3. When I try and run the script in a 1-pixel iframe, I get a 500 error (I assume as it's being run on HTML).

token.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}

$token = $_SESSION['token'];
?>
```

formsubmit.php

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST['token'])) {
        if (hash_equals($_SESSION['token'], $_POST['token'])) {
            $emailbody = 'Name: ' . $_POST['m_title'] . ' ' . $_POST['m_firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['m_surname'] . "\n"
                . 'Email: ' . $_POST['m_email'] . "\n"
                . 'Phone: ' . $_POST['m_phone'] . "\n"
                . 'D.O.B: ' . $_POST['m_dob_day'] . ' ' . $_POST['m_dob_month'] . ' ' . $_POST['m_dob_year'] . "\n"         
                . 'Postcode: ' . $_POST['m_postcode'] . "\n"
                . 'Lenders: ' . $_POST['m_bank1']  . ',' . $_POST['m_bank2'] . ',' . $_POST['m_bank3'] . ',' . $_POST['m_bank4'] . ',' . $_POST['m_bank5'] . ',' . $_POST['m_bank6'] . ',' . $_POST['m_bank7'] . ',' . $_POST['m_bank8'];               
            mail('**removed**', 'Web Lead', $emailbody);
            header('Location: **removed**/thankyou');
            exit();
        }   
        else {
            echo "token invalid";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "token blank";
    }
}
else {
    echo "invalid request";
}
?>
```

My jQuery attempt in index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('token.php');
}); 
</script>
```

Provided the PHP above is not riddled with errors, I had assumed that successfully converting it to index.php would resolve my issues, but I am having difficulty doing so.

Comment: Can you share the entire index.html file content?

Comment: By the way, you should echo the token variable in token.php, otherwise nothing goes out from that file and the ajax response has no content.

Comment: "*converting index.html to index.php loads the body blank*" usually means that .php parsing died (fatal unrecoverable). Your browser should be showing a server 500 error? Check error logs on your server (if you had logging enabled).

Comment: The problem you're having is that `$.get('token.php');` doesn't do anything with the data once it's been returned by the server. Presumably you're wanting to write the output from that script back to your page?

Comment: @Alberto Boss won't let me identify the website, so I can't post the index without stripping out large chunks of it. 
Do I need to take the token generated and set it to a hidden field so I can compare in the formsubmit.php?

Comment: @IncredibleHat They are now, I shall report back once I've done some fiddling around.

Comment: @Andy That was me simply trying to get the script to run. I believe I need to set the token as a variable to post with the form so I can compare it on formsubmit.php  Is that correct?

Comment: @Niall i've posted an answer. Check it out and comment on it if it works/doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code:

`token.php` needs to output the token. Which is as simple as `echo $token;`

The main problem is that you've used the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get('token.php');
});
```

What this means is that when the page (`index.html`) is loaded, your browser makes an ajax request to `token.php`. However... nothing further happens. You're not actually doing anything with the response (output) from `token.php`.

What you need to do is place the response from `token.php` into your web page. Going off the code you've posted I assume there is a form field with the name `"token"`? If this is the case then you would make the ajax request like this, which writes the response of `token.php` to that field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('token.php').done(function(data) {
        $('input[name="token"]').val(data);
    }).fail() {
       // Handle ajax request failure here
    });
)};
```

To answer your questions:

1. `$_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));` means that the variable `$_SESSION['token']` contains your token. That's where you are setting it.
2. If you're getting a 403 error requesting `token.php` in the ajax request this means that the server won't process that request. So it could be a permissions issue or some other problem. Try putting `die('test');` at on the first line of the script and then executing `/token.php` in your browser. Can you access it, or does it give you an error? If it's accessible it will say "test". Check the servers error log if you're unsure why you can't access it. Based on the code, it's unlikely that the URL to the script is wrong, or that'd give you a *404* error.
3. It's unclear why you're bothering with: *"When I try and run the script in a 1-pixel iframe"*. I assume this is an attempt to write the response of `token.php` back to the page. That can be solved by my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am able to access and run php files without issue when I navigate to them in the browser. The 403 and 500 errors seems to be caused by my coding skills. I will address the token issue tomorrow, thank you for the amendments you have provided. 
As for the iFrame, I was being foolish thinking I could get it to run php within the HTML.

Comment: You could get a PHP script to execute inside an iframe, but it's not the right way to achieve anything you're trying to do here. Use jquery to write the output of `token.php` back to your webpage as described above. No need for iframes at all here.